# Can I use Git to apply update patches to customized software?

Tags: git

On one of my websites I have installed forum software (PunBB). Because the software doesn't offer any hooks or filters I have over time added customizations to the core. This means that updating to newer versions becomes more and more cumbersome, because I have to do everything manually.

I have never used Git before, but I've read about it. Most of the use cases start from a clean code base and use Git to track changes, but I have to start from code that has been changed extensively, and add patches to that. I haven't been able to find a way to use Git in my situation and I'd really like to know if this can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, and absolutely should.

- Clone original repository from native source (in your case `git clone https://github.com/punbb/punbb`)
- Create your local branch starting from upstream master branch.
- Create difference between upstream master and your customized copy and commit it into your branch.
- Continue committing your customizations into local branch, and from time to time merge (or sometimes just cherry-pick) from upstream master branch.
- Consider contributing back some of your work - it will make merging easier, eventually.

**EDIT**: expanded step 3 by your request:

1. After cloning upstream repository, create your local development branch (say, `mybranch`) based on upstream master currrent state:

   ```
   git branch mybranch origin/master
   git checkout mybranch
   ```
2. Edit files in this branch to reflect your local patches. However, you want this difference to be as small as possible - don't just blindly replace all files, spend some time thinking if you can stay closer to upstream.
3. Commit this difference into your `mybranch`.
4. From time to time, fetch new commits to master from upstream:

   ```
   git fetch origin
   ```

   and merge those changes into your `mybranch` (assuming that you are on it, if not, checkout to `mybranch` it first):

   ```
   git merge origin/master
   ```

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this, but I have trouble with your third step. Where do I put both sets of files (punBB master vs. my customized version) to create a diff? I tried making a new branch, then overwriting the master files with my code to merge both versions, but I ended up with the exact same files in both branches. Should I keep both in separate directories? But how do I merge them then?

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to do this?